# Edges Direction/normal problem

Tags: edit-mode, edges

when I extrude these edges, some of the normals aren't correct. how can I fix these edges' direction before extrusion?

[image]

**extrude**
[image]

**Solidify**
[image]

**File**

[image]

Comment: usually, it does not occur like in the second image above. What have you started with?

Comment: @lemon I had another object that I needed some of the edges from it. after separation, I saw this problem, I uploaded the blend file.

Comment: ok, I don't know why this occurs from the base edges, but after extrusion, select all and shift+n.

Comment: @lemon thank u, nice shortcut.